# Meaning of $[f,g]$ in Frechet derivative $d^{2}C[f,g]$

Tags: derivatives, frechet-derivative

Let $C$ be a quadratic functional operator of single variable. For example: $C(u)=u^{2}(t)$. The notation $dC$ means Frechet derivative. Although I know that $d^{2}C$ would be a constant since $C$ is quadratic, what does it mean for the following notation?

$$d^{2}C[f,g]$$

An author stated that the above is constant for quadratic $C$.

Comment: I would think it's the second derivative in some form so that $C(f + h) = C(f) + dC(f)h + d^2C(f)(h, h)$. In the case where your functions are in an inner product space $H$, we frequently use $d^2C(f)(h, h) = (h, d^2C(f)h)$, so $d^2C(f) \in L(H)$. Then $d^2C(f)$ is called the Hessian.

Comment: At each point of the domain, the second Frechet derivative is a bilinear map. The $[f,g]$ are just the two inputs you feed into this bilinear map.